# Unexpected results with OpenMP on i7 and Xeon

Tags: c, openmp, parallel-processing

parallelizing two nested for-loops, I have run into behavior I cannot explain. I have tried three different kinds of parallelization using OpenMP on an i7 860 and and a xeon E5540 and I expected that the code behaves more or less the same on both platforms, meaning that one of the platforms should be faster for the all three different cases I tested. But that is not the case:

- For case 1, the Xeon is faster by ~10%,
- for case 2, the i7 is faster by factor 2 and
- for case 3, the Xeon is again faster by the factor 1,5

Do you have an idea what could cause this?

Please state when you need more information or clarification!

To further clarify, my question is meant more general. If I run the same code on an i7 and on a xeon system, shouldn't the use of OpenMP result in comparable (proportional) results?

**pseudo code:**

```
for 1:4
    for 1:1000
        vector_multiplication
    end
end
```

**The cases:**

case 1:
no pramga omp no parallelzation

case 2:
pragma omp for the first for-loop

case 3: 
pragma omp for the second for-loop

**Results**

Here are the actual numbers from the `time` command:

**case 1**

```
Time   Xeon        i7
real   11m14.120s  12m53.679s
user   11m14.030s  12m46.220s
sys      0m0.080s    0m0.176s
```

**case 2**

```
Time   Xeon        i7
real    8m57.144s   4m37.859s
user   71m10.530s  29m07.797s
sys      0m0.300s   0m00.128s
```

**case 3**

```
Time   Xeon        i7
real    2m00.234s   3m35.866s
user   11m52.870s  22m10.799s
sys     0m00.170s   0m00.136s
```

**[Update]**

Thanks for all the hints. I am still researching what the reason could be.

Comment: Are these single-socket systems, or dual?  Do you have hyperthreading turned on?   Could you tell us more about `vector_multiplication` --  is this a scalar-vector product, a dot product, an outer product, or multiplication of a list of numbers c[i] = a[i]*b[i]?

Answer (score 2):

There's been good answers here about possible variations with effects of compilation, etc, which are quite correct; but there are other reasons to expect differences.   A fairly straightforward (eg, low arithmetic intensity) computation like this tends to be very sensitive to memory bandwidth; and the amount of memory bandwidth available per thread will depend on how many threads you run.   Is memory set up the same way on both systems?

It looks like the i7 860 has a higher clock speed, but the E5540 has higher total memory bandwidth.  Since case 2 can only make use of 4 threads, and case 3 can make use of more, it's not at all crazy to think that in the 4-thread case the clock speed wins but in the 8-thread case the increased memory contention (8 threads trying to pull in/push out values) tips the hand to the higher-bandwdith Xeon.

Making this potentially more complicated is the fact that it looks like you're running 8 threads -- are these dual-socket systems or are you using hyperthreading?  This makes the situation much more complicated, since hyperthreading actually helps hide some of the memory contention by switching in threads when another thread is stuck waiting for memory.

If you want to try to see if finite memory bandwidth is playing a role here, you can artificially add more computation to the problem (eg, multiply exp(sin(a)) by cos(b)*cos(b) or something) to ensure the problem is compute-bound, eliminating one variable as you try to get to the bottom of things.   Compiling the code on each system with optimizations for that particular machine (with -march or -xHost or what have you) eliminates another variable.  If hyperthreading is on, turning it off (or just setting OMP_NUM_THREADS to the number of physical cores) gets rid of another variable.   Once you understand what's going on in this simplified case, relaxing the restrictions above one-by-one should help you understand what's going on a little better.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing -- it would also be useful to also get OpenMP numbers for case 2 and 3 with OMP_NUM_THREADS set to 1, to distinguish between the effects of a single thread and the effects of the overhead (possibly due to foregone optimizations) of OpenMP.

Answer (score 0):

Things that can influence the efficiency of openMP are e.g the computation of the iteration bounds. Ensure that these are computed before hand and that the iteration variables are as local as possible. If you have C99 do something like

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = start, is = stop; i < is; ++i) ...
```

to ensure that the expressions `start` and `stop` are evaluated at the beginning. (or use `_Pragma`, see my other answer.)

Then the only way to see if this really was successful is to look at the assembler code (usually option `-S`).

If it isn't look into the other compiler options. `gcc` has the option `-march=native` that compiles optimally for the actual architecture. Other platforms might have similar options. Start by searching for the best architecture options for case 1.

Comment: Hi Jens, thank you very much for your tipps on further improving the use of OpenMP. But my question was meant more general. If I run the same code on an i7 and on a xeon system, shouldn't the use of OpenMP result in comparable (propotional) results?

Comment: @Framester, there is no "should". Such things depend a lot on micro optimizations that depend on how your particular compiler is capable to handle your particular processor and code. They have different number of registers e.g, so a loop body may fit well into registers without spilling for one setting and not for the other. On top of these local optimization decisions you have then openMP that has to do a runtime decision about how it should cut the loop into parallel executions.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer.

It's not entirely clear what you have measured.  For greater certainty I would want to:

1. Insert timing statements at points in my code to report execution time.  That way I know what I am measuring, with more certainty than the Linux time command gives me.
2. Use 2 different compilers, to ensure that I am measuring something about OpenMP rather than aspects of one implementation of it.

All that aside, I tend to agree that your initial results bear further investigation.

One of the things I suggest you try is collapsing your two loops and letting OpenMP schedule 4000 loops rather than 4 or 1000.